# pymysql memory usage is too hight

Tags: python, pymysql

I am using pymysql to query a mysql database. It works fine but the memory consumption is well above my expectation.

For example, for a table that uses about 100 MB disk space if saved as a csv file, when query it with pymysql, it sometimes can use 10 GB of memory.

Anyone has the same problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a sample SQL query that causes this behavior?

Comment: sure. for example, select * from some_table where date='2017-01-31'. The data table has about 10 columns and 1 million rows.

Comment: In the python program, I just use con = pymysql.connect(...), cur=con.cursor(), cur.execute(q), data = cur.fetchall() to get data.